# When viewing a downloaded page in Android Chrome, buttons no longer work. (javascript not running)

Tags: javascript, android, google-chrome, offline

I downloaded my web app page on Android Chrome using the download button in the Chrome menu, and then viewed the downloaded page.  It tells me I’m viewing an offline copy.  There are several buttons on the page with javascript behind them to do something on the page like pop up a message, or do a little onclick code, and they no longer work.  Hyperlinks work but buttons using javascript don’t.  Is that to be expected?

By the way, I have JavaScript enabled in my Android Chrome.  I've tried this on 3 different Android devices.

Comment: Nobody can answer?  Try it now on Amazon's home page.  There's a Welcome! login button over on the top left.  Download that page on an Android device, and view the downloaded page.  The login button doesn't work.  If you have built-in offline caching, it should still run JavaScript behind the button, I would think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We figured it out.  Our DEV and TEST environments didn't have real 3rd party certificates.  They were more home-grown.  Once we installed real SSL certificates, Android devices worked fine - the javascript behind the buttons started working.  And iOS devices worked fine - they created the real icon packaged with the app, instead of a screen short of whatever page you were on.